# Why dot product of two arrays produces a scalar value but dot product of transposed array produce a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

In numpy, I realized the following two calculations produce different results.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
dot_product1 = np.dot(a, b)    <--- I think this should be an error
print(dot_product1)

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(-1,1)
dot_product2 = np.dot(a, b)
print(dot_product2)
```

The dot_product1 is a scalar value 30, but the dot_product2 is a 1x1 matrix, [30].

My understanding of linear algebra is that we cannot calculate dot product of a 1 x 4 matrix with another 1 x 4 matrix. I expect the third line fail but it is successful.

The second part of the code calculates a 1 x 4 matrix and a 4 x 1 matrix, which produces a 1 x 1 matrix. This is what I expected.

Can someone help explain what is the difference between these to calculations?

Comment: NumPy is an n-dimensional array library, not a matrix library. `np.array([1,2,3,4])` is 1-dimensional, not a 1x4 matrix.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. But numpy does not allow me to calculate dot product of a 3 x 4 array and a 3 x 5 array. This is not allowed in linear algebra too. But I can calculate 3 x 4 array and a 4 x 5 array. This is like matrix multiplication.

Comment: This is pretty much covered by the docs over on https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html? (`.dot` does _quite_ a number of different things depending on what input you give it).

Comment: `np.dot` handles both inner product (scalar product) and matrix multiplication, depending on the shape of the arguments.  While you can do all linear-algebra calculations with `numpy`, `numpy` is not strict linear algebra.  `numpy` arrays can be 0d, 1d, 3d etc.  Plain linear algebra is only 2d (that applies to column and row vectors as well.  `np.dot` docs should be clear enough regarding the different allowed shapes.  You can also read `np.matmul` docs, which for 1 and 2d arrays are compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the `np.dot` docs?  Pay attention to what it says about 1d arguments?

```
In [209]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...: b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...: dot_product1 = np.dot(a, b)
     ...: print(dot_product1, type(dot_product1))
     ...: 
     ...: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...: b = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(-1,1)
     ...: dot_product2 = np.dot(a, b)
     ...: print(dot_product2, type(dot_product2), dot_product2.shape)
30 <class 'numpy.int32'>
[30] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1,)

In [210]: a.shape, b.shape
Out[210]: ((4,), (4, 1))
```

The first does produce a scalar, an inner product.  Same as `np.sum(a*b)`. (Corrected)

It's the `dot` of a (4,) element array with another (4,) array  These are not (1,4) 'row vectors'.

The second combines a (4,) with a (4,1), producing a (1,) shape.  Not a 1x1!

If you want a (1,1) dot a (1,4) with a (4,1)

```
In [211]: (a[None,:]@b).shape
Out[211]: (1, 1)
```

One 'dot product' page says it can be calculated as `Algebraically, the dot product is defined as the sum of the products of the corresponding entries of the two sequences of numbers.`  That's exactly what your first example does.

Matrix multiplication can be thought of as the application of the `dot product` to all row/column combinations of a 2 matrices.  That's what `np.dot` does, with the intermediate option of working with a 2d and a 1d array (your second example).

`np.dot` can also work with 3+d arrays, though the `matmul` version is generally more useful.

If you want a further challenge, look at `np.einsum`, which applies 'Einstein notation' to these multidimensional products.

Generally, in `np.dot(A,B)`, the last dimension of `A` pairs with the 2nd to the last dimension (or only dimension if 1d) of `B`.  In `einsum` terms I like to think of that as the 'sum of products' dimension.

[https://mkang32.github.io/python/2020/08/23/dot-product.html#:~:text=Matrix%20multiplication%20is%20basically%20a,of%20vectors%20in%20each%20matrix](https://mkang32.github.io/python/2020/08/23/dot-product.html#:%7E:text=Matrix%20multiplication%20is%20basically%20a,of%20vectors%20in%20each%20matrix).

> Matrix multiplication is basically a matrix version of the dot product. Remember the result  of dot product is a scalar. The result of matrix multiplication is a matrix, whose elements are the dot products of pairs of vectors in each matrix.

Comment: did you mean to write `np.sum(a,b)` or was the comma an oversight and meant `np.sum(a*b)`??